# Can Hystrix be used for scheduling jobs like the job scheduler in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

I am comparing all methods of job scheduling within a Spring Boot application that requires several services to several applications.  I have been told that Hystrix is an alternative.  My understanding from my own personal use is that Hystrix is a circuit breaker suitable for detecting errored jobs.  I am wondering if I am wrong and Hystrix can be adapted for scheduling jobs?

Answer (score 0):

No, Hystrix has nothing to do with scheduling jobs. It is a latency and fault tolerance library.

Typical Java libraries for scheduling jobs are:

- [Spring Task Scheduler](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)
- [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)
- [Cron4j](https://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/)